# MYSQL Connector Python Issue | Select Query

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having a problem with this MySQL Query, how can I fix that?

```
 valori = (message.from_user.id, message.from_user.username)
 verifica = "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE ID = %s, Username = %s"
 cursor.execute(verifica, valori)
```

A sample of variable "valori":
`(1062473636, 'Partizionare')`

Error:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' Username = 'Partizionare'' at line 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lello/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 217, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "/home/lello/Documents/Telegram/LelloDevBot/pyro.py", line 19, in start
    cursor.execute(verifica, valori)
  File "/home/lello/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/home/lello/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/home/lello/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' Username = 'Partizionare'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as `,` in conditions, you mean `AND`.

Comment: Thank you. I used to make query like in php.

Comment: Well, I'm just a little bit confused then. I haven't work with databases in a while. Anyway, thank you for the help.